# node.js request package has syntax error

Tags: node.js, request

I just installed the latest request package, npm install request.
In my app, I have set the `NODE_DEBUG=request` so now I get a syntax error:

```
node_modules/request/lib/debug.js

module.exports =
function debug () {
  if (/\brequest\b/.test(process.env.NODE_DEBUG))
    console.error('REQUEST %s', util.format.apply(util, arguments))
}

ReferenceError: util is not defined
```

Any thoughts on this? What is "util"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`util`](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html) is one of the core node.js modules. The file should have a require for the module (`var util = require('util')`) but it's missing. It's a bug in the request library itself.

It has been fixed but this hasn't been published to the npm repository yet:

https://github.com/mikeal/request/commit/b8cf8743b66d8eee4048561a7d81659f053393c8

Comment: Did you just happen to know that ? :)

Comment: @reza - I thought I'd take a look at `debug.js` on GitHub and the last checkin comment was related to that fix. It was just fortuitous really :)